# knockout.js, afterrender function doesnt work as expected

Tags: templates, knockout.js, render, highlight.js

I got an issue with my code, im using hljs to highlight my code snippets which im using. I wrote a template system, as example the general input would be this:

```
<codeexample params="type: html">
  <div style="example_class">Example code</div>
</codeexample>
```

My template interpreter:

```
<template id="codeexample">
  <div class="code">
    <pre><code data-bind="attr: {class: type}, template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes, afterRender: $root.handleCode}, visible: false ">
    </code></pre>
  </div>
</template>
```

My handleCode function:

```
this.handleCode = function(element) {
  var preCodeTags = $(element).find('pre code');
  preCodeTags.each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    block.show(100);
  });
}
```

The problem is that the afterRender function is called already before the template is rendered to my actual template, i used to add a `console.log($(element).find('pre code'));` which had the result that the length was 0.

```
[prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[3], context: undefined, selector:
"pre code", constructor: function, init: function…] 
context: undefined
length: 0
```

Shouldnt the function `afterRender` run exactly after the render process?
Is there a known work around? When I use a timeout for 200ms, it works fine, but this is the worst solution in my opinion.

Comment: Please create a repro in jsfiddle! Also please include your `codeexample` component definition in your question! By the why which KO version are you using? `$componentTemplateNodes` is not yet officially released ... it will be included in version 3.3

Comment: Probably its a bit difficult to add a fiddle, because im using html imports on a single page application where each page has his own template file.
You are right, im including 3.3alpha, because i wanted to use nested components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `afterRender` handler isn't quite right.  The parameter (`element` in your case) is actually an *array of all elements rendered*.  From [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-4-using-afterrender-afteradd-and-beforeremove):

```
viewModel.myPostProcessingLogic = function(elements) {
    // "elements" is an array of DOM nodes just rendered by the template
    // You can add custom post-processing logic here
}
```

So it's not finding the `code` element successfuly.  You could do this instead:

```
this.handleCode = function(elements) {
  var preCodeTags = $(elements).filter('div').find('pre code');
  preCodeTags.each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    block.show(100);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answere, this is probably not working, it also doesn't filter in that case any pre-code tags.

Comment: @Grief-Code Can you `console.log` the parameter itself rather than your jQuery `$().find` around it - double check exactly what you're being passed?

Comment: Okay, it returns me an array: `[text, div, text]` the first `div` includes this: `<code data-bind="template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes, afterRender: $root.handleCode}, attr: {class: type.length > 0 ? type : ''}" class="html">↵        <div style="example">I'm an example element!</div>↵      </code>` looking like what im actually wanting.

Comment: @Grief-Code thanks - updated the answer.  It now filters the array to get just the `div`, then `find`s the `pre code` as before.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it took me some minutes, but the actual selector for the `<code>` tag is this `$(elements).filter('div').parent()` i only have one small error but this is not relating to the question.